# Rescaling in R, fixed to percentile

Tags: r

I understand how to use rescale, but I'm unsure how I could modify it so rather than scaling the min and max (to a 0-100) scale, it scales the min to 0 and x percentile to 100.

Example:

```
Raw       0-100 scaling (wrong)   0-100 scaling (right [using 75th perecntile as max])
0         0                       0
1         10                      50
2         20                      100
10        100                     500
```

Current code is:

```
data$Predict_Party <- rescale(data$Predict_Party_Unscaled, to = c(0, 100))
```

Additional: How would you recommend I then determine the formula of the transformation that was used? Ie scaled = unscaled*x + y

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25894/changing-the-scale-of-a-variable-to-0-100) you can find a discussion regarding the formula of the transformation with further references

Comment: @Crimc I've already seen this discussion and it was insufficient, hence I asked this question. In every case, they're only scaling based on the min and max values, not a middle value of some form.

Comment: `rescale(your_vector, to = c(0,100), from = c(0, quantile(raw, .75, type = 1)))`

Comment: @onyambu I get ```Error in quantile.default(raw, 0.98, type = 1) : 
  anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'``` I should have specified that I do have NA's in there (which I want to exclude; ie percentiles based on actual data values, not NAs).

Comment: Just omit the `NA`s. You just said you have NA's and you would like to omit them. Just omit them.

Comment: Probably you mean you do not know how to omit them? okay `rescale(your_vector, to = c(0,100), from = c(0, quantile(na.omit(raw), .75, type = 1)))`

Answer (score 1):

Per helpful comment on the choice of algorithm  I believe this is the answer.

```r
library(scales)
raw <- c(0, 1, 2, NA, 10)
rescale(raw, to = c(0,100), from = c(0, quantile(na.omit(raw), .75, type = 1)))
#> [1]   0  50 100  NA 500
df <- data.frame(raw)
df$rescaled <- rescale(df$raw, to = c(0,100), from = c(0, quantile(na.omit(df$raw), .75, type = 1)))
df
#>   raw rescaled
#> 1   0        0
#> 2   1       50
#> 3   2      100
#> 4  NA       NA
#> 5  10      500
```

Comment: OP is correct. Please note that there are different quantile formulas. try `rescale(raw, to = c(0,100), from = c(0, quantile(raw, .75, type = 1)))`

Comment: @ChuckP Hmm, this doesn't seem to be doing anything, and its also not quite what I wanted. I wanted to set the 100 point as the 98th percentile, with values continuing to exceed this. Hence in my example, there is a '500'.

Comment: What do you mean it's not doing anything?  And you say in your post you wanted the 75th percentile.  If you want 98th just sub in 98 where it says .75

Comment: @ChuckP I mean that with ```data$Predict_Trust_Unscaled <- predict(DisputeRegression_Trust) ``` and ```data$Predict_Trust <- rescale(data$Predict_Trust_Unscaled, to = c(0,100), from = c(0, quantile(na.omit(data$Predict_Trust_Unscaled), .98, type = 1)))``` the data remains the same as it was in _Unscaled.

Its not the 98th vs 75th percentile I'm worried about, its the bounds. I want "100" to be the 98th percentile, not the 100th. Maybe I was testing with someone else's suggestion and your function was not changing things, hence I thought it was your code doing that.

Comment: Weirdly, summary seems to suggest the minimum isn't zero, otherwise the percentiles do look good.
`summary(data$Predict_Trust)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  -45.2    -5.3    10.4    17.9    36.2   369.0    9498 
 round(quantile(data$Predict_Trust, c(.60, .90, .98, 0.99, 0.995, 0.9975), na.rm=TRUE),1)
   60%    90%    98%    99%  99.5% 99.75% 
  18.0   61.3  100.0  117.2  131.0  139.6`

Comment: Okay now you're talking about summaries of data I don't have access to enjoy your weekend.